# How to Load Several Swift WKWebviews and Know When They Are All Done

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am using `WKWebView` to render several (around 100) web pages that I then need to render to PDF. I am using the `createPDF` method of `WKWebView` to accomplish this. The reason I'm doing each individual page in its own web view is because `createPDF` doesn't respect page breaks in the HTML (as far as I know).

So I have a class where I start the loop to render each page:

```
class PrintVC: ViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
  var pages = [Page]()

  func start(){
    //A "page" is a struct that has the string content to load each web view
    for page in pages{
      let webView = WKWebView()
      webView.navigationDelegate = self
      webView.loadHTMLString(page.content, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
    }
  }
}
```

I know the page is ready to be saved to PDF in the `didFinish navigation` delegate method:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    
  let config = WKPDFConfiguration()
  config.rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 792, height: 612)
    
  //Create the PDF
  webView.createPDF(configuration: config){ result in
    switch result{
      case .success(let data):
        do{
          try data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "file-???.pdf"))
        }catch let error{
          print(error)
        }
      case .failure(let error):
         print(error)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The trouble I'm having is I don't know when each individual page is done rendering. I also don't know how to pass each page's name to be used in the file path to save it.

How can I start a bunch of `WKWebView` loads and know when they are all done? Or better still, how can I reuse the same `WKWebView` and load each individual page in the same way? I assume using the same web view would be a better use of memory.

Comment: "how can I reuse the same WKWebView and load each individual page in the same way?" Is that actually better? You would be loading each page sequentially, and I'd imagine that would be slower (this is just a hunch though, no real evidence).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I start a bunch of `WKWebView` loads and know when they are all done?

Well, you'd need to identify which web view caused the delegate method to be called. It is for this reason that the first parameter - `webView: WKWebView` - exists.

One way is to put each (web view, pair) into a dictionary (`[WKWebView: Page]`). Then start the loading:

```
// assume you have declared a property "self.webViewDict"
for page in pages{
  let webView = WKWebView()
  webView.navigationDelegate = self

  self.webViewDict[webView] = page
  webView.loadHTMLString(page.content, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
}
```

When one finishes loading, you can identify the page by doing `webViewDict[webView]`. You should then remove the web view from the dictionary:

```
webViewDict[webView] = nil
if webViewDict.isEmpty {
    // everything is loaded!
}
```

> how can I reuse the same WKWebView and load each individual page in the same way?

Note that if you use the same `WKWebView`, you'll have to load the pages sequentially. The same web view can't load multiple things at the same time.

You can just removed the loaded pages from `pages`. If you don't want to do that, you can copy `pages` to another `var` first.

In `start`, load the first page:

```
if let firstPage = pages.first {
    webView.loadHTMLString(firstPage.content, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
}
```

When you successfully load a page, do the same thing again:

```
case .success(let data):
    pages.removeFirst()
    if let firstPage = pages.first {
        webView.loadHTMLString(firstPage.content, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
    } else {
        // we are done!
    }
```

Comment: This is great! I think creating multiple `WKWebView`s will be better. It'll use a lot more memory, but it should be much quicker. Thank you!